# IP address + sub net mask validation

Tags: c#

in my application users enter the ip address + sub net mask like this:
192.168.0.0/16 or 80.80.80.0/24 and i want to validate it like this:

1. if the ip address is not a valid address then return false.(its easy and
   i can do it with `IPAddress.TryParse` method)
2. if the ip address is not a public address then return
   false.(192.168.0.0/16=false)
3. if the sub net mask is invalid.(its not between 0 and 32).

I'm new in c# and i really appreciated if you tell me the best way to validate the ip address.
thank you.

Comment: You can use regex. See this article http://blog.markhatton.co.uk/2011/03/15/regular-expressions-for-ip-addresses-cidr-ranges-and-hostnames/

Comment: thanks. but i prefer not to use the regex.

Comment: Regex is not needed in this case for a simple string split.  I would split first around the '/' then split around the period.

Comment: You'd really accept a subnet mask of 0? Which, effectively, means "the whole IPv4 internet, including private address ranges".

Comment: actually yes. it means all ip addresses can access to web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to do some search because your question might has answered before.

For Q1, please refer to [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499269/how-to-check-if-an-ip-address-is-within-a-particular-subnet).

For Q2 and Q3, it can easily be checked after you split the input string (like @RPradeep's answer)

After all, I suggest you to find a better 3rd party "C# IP address library". I think your requirement is common usage and somebody might do the same before. It better than you do it again by yourself, right?

**UPDATE**

For Q2, there's still [a stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113546/how-to-determine-whether-an-ip-address-in-private) could help you.

**UPDATE**

According your comment, I recommend another way for you - how about list all IP address which you want to return false, and check a target IP address can be found in the list or not?

For IPv4, there's a [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2553/IP-list-Check-an-IP-number-against-a-list-in-C) can build the IP address list for you - in easy way.

Comment: thank you. but i already search and unfortunately cant found any thing. if you know a dll or anything might help i really appreciated let me know.

Comment: I could provide what I know to you, but I recommend you practice your google-fu, sincerely :)  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thank you. i already saw this post. unfortunately its not occurrence. for example the 169.254.0.0/16 is not a valid ip address range.

Comment: @Dan Okay, so you want to check all about those reserved IP address which list in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Special-use_addresses ? I find another way, please see my newest update.

Comment: Thank you so much. but i think i found something better: [link](http://ipnetwork.codeplex.com/). what do you think?

Comment: I have read the documentation, I'm not sure it will cover all your question, but it worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the string contains a ":",
//This is IPv6

If the string starts with fd, then return false

Else:
You can parse the String with split on "." 
//This is for IPv4
1. If it starts with 10. , then return false
2. If it starts with 172.16 , and subnet is 12 , then return false
3. If it starts with 192.168 , and subnet is 16, then return false

Finally, split on / and see the 2nd part and parse the Integer. If it does not fall in range of 0 and 32, then return false

Comment: IPv6 is never going to take off if people keep writing code for IPv4.

Comment: Question here was for IPv4

Comment: The question was for an IP address. Nowhere the question did he state "I don't want this code to continue working as we transition to IPv6"

Comment: Incorporated the changes for IPv6